# C++ atoi with unsigned char

Tags: c++, atoi

I got an unsigned char with the value of 1, I need to put this in a string like "1".
But if I try to put this directly into a stringstream it will get the value of char(1) and I need it to be "1".
I know that if I can get this into the function atoi it will return the "1" value.
But I tried to cast it to char and put it in the atoi function, but it throws an exception.
Already tried to put it in a string and them cast c_str() into atoi function, but without success yet.
If someone can help me I'll apreciate.

Comment: You need to post actual code as your question makes little sense as it stands.

Comment: Note that `[unsigned] char` types are meant to be textual characters (while they also serve as a one-byte integer value). In the memory, textual characters and numbers look the same, but written in a string they don't (a number is written in several digits, while a character remains one character). Therefore, stringstream will write this as one character into the target string, so you see something unexpected. The problem is that stringstream doesn't *know* if your char is meant to represent a character or a number.

Answer (score 3):

Simply cast a `char` to an `int` before inserting it into the `std::stringstream`:

```
ss << static_cast<int>(c);
```

This will treat the value of the `char` not as a character but as a numerical value.

Comment: Or maybe `unsigned int`, depending on what the higher values should look like. +1.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're confusing two functions here.

You wish to convert an integer to a string.

`atoi` (ascii to integer) however takes a string and parses it into an integer, making `"123"` into `123`.

You are looking for the `itoa` function here, which has this prototype:

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

In your case, this would look like this:

```
char Buf[10];
itoa(123, Buf, 10);
printf("%s", Buf); //Outputs 123
```

Please remember though, that itoa is not part of the standard, even though it is supported by some compilers. For a more standard-compliant version use:

```
sprintf(Buf, "%d", 123);
```

Of course all of this is plain C, but any C++ compiler will work with this all the same.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a numeric value in the range [0,9] to the corresponding character, just add `'0'` to it. That's guaranteed to work on all systems.